# what will happened if I put same or different name war in running jboss server

Tags: jboss

I am really new to jboss and I need to know some behaviors of jboss.

Here is my scenario, we are using **jboss-6.1.0.Final**

I am using jetkins for preparing war, now war is ready now I have planned to use FTP plugin to upload war on server. Up to this everything is fine but what I need to know is

I have ftp root path is `C:\jboss-6.1.0.Final\server\RCM\deploy`.

So if I deploy same war(or with same war with changing name) without stopping server because jetkins takes time to prepare war so I don't want to stop it until war is ready.

**So my main query is what will happened if I put same or different name war in running server? will it stop currently running server?**

Any help will highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It will not stop running server. It could start redeploying war if war name is same. 
if it has different name then It could start deployment of new war.